# lock a page behind a password

Tags: php, html, pdo

I'm trying to lock out a certain page to one user, with a username and a password. I tried a couple things, but what I think I need is a sort of login function. I have made logins before, so I used code of mine that I used before. For some reason however, it gives me an error that I coded in to know that the password is incorrect, even though it isn't. To make it a bit easier to see which specific error message is given, I've put in a 1 and a 2 behind the error, i get error number 1.

Below is my php code and below that is my html form I use.

```
$username = $password = "";
                    $username_err = $password_err = $login_err = "";
                  
                    function pr($data, $kill_script = false)
                  {
                      echo '<pre>'.print_r($data,1).'</pre>';
                      if($kill_script) exit;
                   }
                  
                      // Processing form data when form is submitted
                      if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
                   
                      // Check if username is empty
                      if(empty(trim($_POST["username"]))){
                          $username_err = "Please enter username.";
                      }
                      else{
                          $username = trim($_POST["username"]);
                      }
                      
                      // Check if password is empty
                      if(empty(trim($_POST["password"]))){
                          $password_err = "Please enter your password.";
                      }
                      else{
                          $password = trim($_POST["password"]);
                      }
                  
                          // Validate Credentials
                          if(empty($username_err) && empty($password_err)){
                              //prepare a select statement
                              $sql = "SELECT username, password FROM user_confirm WHERE username = :username";
                      
                  
                              if($stmt = $conn->prepare($sql)){
                                  // bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
                                  $stmt->bindParam(":username", $param_username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                                  //set parameters
                                  $param_username = trim($_POST["username"]);
                                  if($stmt->execute()){
                  
                                      // check if username exits, if yes then verify password
                                      
                                      if($stmt->rowCount() == 1){
                                          if($row = $stmt->fetch()){
                                              $username = $row["username"];
                                              $hashed_password = $row["password"];
                  
                  
                                              if(password_verify($password, $hashed_password)){
                                                  // password is correct, so start new session
                                                  session_start();
                                                  
                                                  //store data in session variables
                                                  $_SESSION["loggedin"] = true;
                                                  $_SESSION["username"] = $username;
                  
                                                  //redirect user to welcome page
                                                  header("location: werk_edit.php");
                                              }
                                              else{
                                                  //invalid password, display error message
                                                  $login_err = "Invalid username or password. 1";
                                              }
                                          }
                                      }
                                      else{
                                          //username doesn't exist, display error message
                  
                                          $login_err = "Invalid username or password. 2";
                                      }   
                                  }
                                  else{
                                      echo "Something went wrong, please try again later.";
                                  }
                  
                                  //close statement
                                  unset($stmt);
                              }
                          }
                  
                          //close connection
                          unset($conn);
                      }
```

HTML Form:

```
 <?php 
                    if(!empty($login_err)){
                        echo '<div class="alert alert-danger">' . $login_err . '</div>';
                    }        
                    ?>

                    <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method="post">
                        
                            <label>Username</label>
                            <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control <?php echo (!empty($username_err)) ? 'is-invalid' : ''; ?>" value="<?php echo $username; ?>">
                            <span class="invalid-feedback"><?php echo $username_err; ?></span>
                          
                            <label>Password</label>
                            <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control <?php echo (!empty($password_err)) ? 'is-invalid' : ''; ?>">
                            <span class="invalid-feedback"><?php echo $password_err; ?></span>
                        
                            <input type="submit" name="login" class="btn btn-primary" value="Login">
                        
                    </form>
```

Comment: If you get your error "1", this means that `password_verify($password, $hashed_password)` returned false. Are you sure that you are entering the correct password?

Comment: @NoahBoegli 100% positive. Just tried it again with copy pasting straight from my database, still same error message. This is what's confusing me.

Comment: Hum, how can you copy it from the database if it's hashed? Are you sure you are not confusing `hashed` and `plain` passwords?

Comment: @NoahBoegli I hard coded the username and password into the database before I added this code. Back then I didn't think I needed something this complex for just locking out a page.

Comment: Do you understand what password_verify does, then? It compares the raw password entered by the user to (what it assumes is) the _hashed_ password in the database (which needs to have been created earlier by calling the php password_hash() function, normally this is done when a user registers for the site and/or changes their password via the site.). If you just entered a plain password by hand without using password_hash() then password_verify() cannot be used to check it. Just use ==.

Comment: TBH if you just want to secure a single page you _could_ do that via a simple username/password check set by Apache - you can configure it in a .htaccess file, for example. This would just use HTTP basic auth. You don't necessarily need a full-blown PHP-based login module. https://www.google.com/search?q=apache+set+username+password

Comment: If you store your passwords in plain text, which **you should never do, no matter how complex your system is**, you don't want to use `password_verify` as it will verify that the plain password matches the hash, instead you want to use a simple comparison.

Comment: @ADyson Thank you for your simple explanation! It works how I want it to work. I know this way isn't the most secure, but my website is not online yet, so when that does happen, I'll probably change it.